# Loop through array of objects to multiple tabular form

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $properties as follows

```
Array
    (
    [car] => array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                [brand] => feature1
                [material] => material1
                [type] => type1
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [brand] => feature2
                [material] => material2
                [type] => type2
            )

        )

    [bus] => array
        (
            [0] => Array (
                [brand] => feature3
                [material] => material3
                [type] => type3
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [brand] => feature4
                [material] => material4
                [type] => type4
            )

        )
    )
```

Loop through the above array so that it will display multiple tabular forms. Is any way to do that?

Comment: What did you try so far ? And by the way it's not objects, just basic array

Comment: ^^ agree. But you need to include some expected result to. We won't guess what you want.

Comment: *"Is any way to do that?"* Yes : *"Loop through the above array"*.

Comment: I want a single loop to display car in one table and bus in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 : Create the array:**

```
 $arr = array('car' => array('0' => array('brand' => 'feature1','material' => 'material1','type' => 'type1'),
            '1' => array('brand' => 'feature2','material' => 'material2','type' => 'type2'),
            '2' =>  array('brand' => 'feature3','material' => 'material3','type' => 'type3')),
            
            'bus' => array('0' => array('brand' => 'feature4','material' => 'material4','type' => 'type4'),
            '1' => array('brand' => 'feature5','material' => 'material5','type' => 'type5'),
            '2' =>  array('brand' => 'feature6','material' => 'material6','type' => 'type6')));
```

**Step 2: Looping through the array:**

```
foreach ($arr as $veh){
    foreach($veh as $det){
            echo $det['brand'].' '.$det['material'].' '.$det['type'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> feature1 material1 type1
>
> feature2 material2 type2
>
> feature3 material3 type3
>
> feature4 material4 type4
>
> feature5 material5 type5
>
> feature6 material6 type6

**Copy the below code as save it as .php.
Show as table:**

```
            <?php
        $arr = array('car' => array('0' => array('brand' => 'feature1','material' => 'material1','type' => 'type1'),
                                    '1' => array('brand' => 'feature2','material' => 'material2','type' => 'type2'),
                                    '2' =>  array('brand' => 'feature3','material' => 'material3','type' => 'type3')),
                     'bus' => array('0' => array('brand' => 'feature4','material' => 'material4','type' => 'type4'),
                                    '1' => array('brand' => 'feature5','material' => 'material5','type' => 'type5'),
                                    '2' =>  array('brand' => 'feature6','material' => 'material6','type' => 'type6')));
        echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        }
        td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>';            
        foreach ($arr as $veh){
            echo '<h1>'.array_search ($veh, $arr).'</h1>';
            echo '<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        </tr>';
            foreach($veh as $det){
                echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$det['brand'].'</td>
        <td>'.$det['material'].'</td>
        <td>'.$det['type'].'</td>
        </tr>';
                // echo $det['brand'].' '.$det['material'].' '.$det['type'].'<br>';
            }
            echo '</table>
        </body>
        </html>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Tha's I wanted. But How can I integrate these array values in HTML table form? Car array values combine together in a single table with a single <thead> and <tbody> and bus array values combine together another HTML table with a single <thead> and <tbody>.

Comment: yeah thats nice. If the answer has helped you please upvote it.

Comment: I tried to upvote it. but it showing "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded," I am new to StackOverflow. I don't have enough reputation to upvote it.